# How to bind Shark to an running iPhone app on the device?

Tags: iphone, performance, shark

I was reading at an apple site that shark captures everything that is running on my mac. Thats stupid. I want it to be constrained only to my iPhone app on the device, but there's just nothing to select the executable or something like that. Also in xcode, "Run > Run with Performance Tool > Shark" is grayed out. But shark 4.6x is running.

Are there any videos (except the WWDC stuff for 1500 bucks) that show how to use Shark with an iPhone app on a device? (I mean how to analyze performance while an app runs on the device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create your symbols manually, according to [this doc](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/SharkUserGuide/AdvancedProfileAnalysisandDataMining/AdvancedProfileAnalysisandDataMining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005233-CH7-SW3), Shark will show the application name instead of the address space, according to [this doc](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/SharkUserGuide/SelectingExecutiontoSampleorTrace/SelectingExecutiontoSampleorTrace.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005233-CH13-SW19).  Don't know of any videos, but that second document should walk you through it pretty clearly.

Basically, in Shark, select Sampling > Network/iPhone profiling (shift-command-N).

Comment: How would I bind the symbols of the app to shark, so that it knows them?

Comment: Sorry - just saw this now.
Build a version of your app with debugging symbols.  Choose File ->Symbolicate from the Shark menu and select the debug version of your binary to add the symbols to the Shark session.  The names of the binaries should match.